# Finding the index of the element, for each column in a dataframe, that is the closest to a given defined number and plot in a heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, heatmap

I am basically loading a dataframe from a .csv file in which as the index, I have the motion amplitude values and in the column names, I have the motion frequency values. Filling the column and rows I have the velocity values correspondent to the motion of each frequency and amplitude. What I am planning to achieve is, for each column, to find the closest index and column values to a given number, in this case, let's say it is ***6***, and then plot these values in a heatmap.

I made a dummy example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# Creating a dummy dataframe for the examples
c1 = [6, 3, 2, 3, 8, 2]
c2 = [1, 5.2, 2, 7, 3, 4]
c3 = [3, 5, 6.1, 3, 4, 5.7]
c4 = [5, 8, 1, 6.2, 3, 4]
c5 = [1, 2, 5, 5, 6.3, 7]
c6 = [1, 3, 5.5, 1, 7, 6.1]

df = pd.DataFrame([c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6]).T

# Setting the values for the index and the columns 
index = pd.Index(['0.1', '0.2', '0.3', '0.4', '0.5', '0.6'])
df = df.set_index(index)
df.columns = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

# Plotting the heat map
plt.figure()
ax = sns.heatmap(df)
plt.ylabel('Amplitude [m]')
plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.show()
```

The plot that I want to achieve is the one in the picture below. The yellow line would mark the closest values in each column to the number 6. So, besides the heatmap, I would have to also plot the index and values for each column, in which the number is the closest to 6.

[image]

Comment: It's a coincidence that the yellow line is on the diagonal, I guess?

Comment: If there are 2 values closed to the number 6?

Comment: @Corralien  I did that on purpose for the sake of the example. It is very unlikely that there are 2 equal EXACTLY equal values since I am working with a lot of decimals

Comment: It's a coincidence that the yellow line is on the diagonal, I guess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
# Each square has a dimension of 1x1
# 0.5 to get the center of the square
y = np.argmin(np.abs(6 - df.values), axis=0) + 0.5
x = np.arange(0, 6) + 0.5
ax.plot(x, y, c='y', lw=4)
```

Input:

```
# I slightly modified your dataframe for demo purpose
>>> df
        1     2    3     4     5     6
0.1   8.0   1.0   3.0   5.0   1.0   1.0
0.2   3.0  (5.2)  5.0   8.0   2.0   3.0
0.3   2.0   2.0   5.7   1.0   5.0   5.5
0.4   3.0   7.0   3.0  (6.2)  5.0   1.0
0.5  (6.0)  3.0   4.0   3.0  (6.3)  7.0
0.6   2.0   4.0  (6.1)  4.0   7.0  (6.1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Or as a pandas chain: `y = df.reset_index(drop=True).rsub(6).abs().idxmin().add(0.5)`

Comment: @tdy. I thought about the same solution but I didn't like the `reset_index(drop=True)` and I used `numpy` to compute `x` :-)

Answer (score 0):

The distance function calculates the absolute distance between two given numbers. The Applymap applies the distance function on every element of the dataframe, df.
The default cmap is sns.cm.rocket. To reverse it set cmap to sns.cm.rocket_r.
If you reverse then the smaller numbers will have a darker color.
The “flare” and “crest” colormaps are a better choice for lines or points.

```
def distance_fun(x, y=6):
    return abs(x-y)

# Plotting the heat map
plt.figure()
cmap = sns.cm.flare_r
#cmap = sns.cm.crest_r
ax = sns.heatmap(df.applymap(distance_fun), cmap = cmap)
plt.ylabel('Amplitude [m]')
plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.show()
```